# Make a SQL view showing showing data from 3 tables like crosstab

Tags: asp.net, sql, asp.net-membership

I'm using ASP.net membership system with SQL Server 2000 database.  What I want to do is create a view (or stored proc if that's better) which will return a table with the following columns:

```
UserName  |  Role1  |  Role2  |  Role3  |  ....  | Role*N*
```

Where the columns (besides Username) are generated to include all the ASP.net Roles in the application.

I need this to be generic (i.e. when I add a new Role, I want the procedure/view to compensate and list that new Role as a new column).  I want the values in the Role fields to be 1 (True) or 0 (false) if a user in in that role.  I can make a table that has such columns using Dynamic SQL to create the variable number of columns, but I cannot seem to populate them.

How can I accomplish this?

Tables involved are shown below:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[aspnet_Users](
    [ApplicationId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [UserId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [UserName] [nvarchar](256) NOT NULL,
    [LoweredUserName] [nvarchar](256) NOT NULL,
    [MobileAlias] [nvarchar](16) NULL,
    [IsAnonymous] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [LastActivityDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [UserId] ASC
) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]



CREATE TABLE [dbo].[aspnet_Roles](
    [ApplicationId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [RoleId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [RoleName] [nvarchar](256) NOT NULL,
    [LoweredRoleName] [nvarchar](256) NOT NULL,
    [Description] [nvarchar](256) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [RoleId] ASC
) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]



CREATE TABLE [dbo].[aspnet_UsersInRoles](
    [UserId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [RoleId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [UserId] ASC,
    [RoleId] ASC
) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: This seems like a general "rows into columns" type query.   You could try reasking the question with less emphasis on Membership and posting the relevant table definitions.  Some of the more SQL-savvy users may then answer the question.

Comment: Maybe your right.  I've added definitions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Views can't dynamically add columns based on the data in them.  Neither can straight queries.  Since you want it to automatically change based on the data in the table, this completely rules out views and queries using constructs like `pivot`.

Pretty much your only choice, given the constraints you've given us, is to generate a temp table with enough columns (dynamically), and populate that.  This is still problematic as a sproc can't create and return a temp table since the table would be dropped when the sproc exits.

Another option is to write a sproc which dynamically generates a `pivot` query and executes that.  This is going to be pretty messy though.  Do new roles get added so often that this is an absolute requirement?  That's the only thing that's making it so difficult.

A static pivot query to give you the output you want might look something like this:

```
select
  UserName,
  [1] as Role1, [2] as Role2, [3] as Role3 -- UpdateMe
from (
  select
    u.UserName,
    r.RoleID
    IsUserInRole(u.UserName, r.RoleName) RoleFlag
  from
    aspnet_users u
    cross join aspnet_roles r) source
  pivot (
    RoleFlag for RoleID in 
      ([1],[2],[3]) -- UpdateMe
  ) PivotTable
```

There are two lines that your dynamic SQL generator would have to keep updated, they are marked with the `UpdateMe` comments.

I don't have MSSQL installed here, so I can't test this query, but it should be quite close.  The [`pivot`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx) reference might be helpful.

Faking pivots in SQL Server 2000 using aggregates and `case`:

```
select
  UserName,
  max(case when src.RoleID = 1 then RoleFlag else 0 end) Role1,  --Repeat N times
  ...
from (
  select
    u.UserName,
    r.RoleID
    IsUserInRole(u.UserName, r.RoleName) RoleFlag
  from
    aspnet_users u
    cross join aspnet_roles r) src
group by
  UserName
```

Comment: I insist on having the new roles appear.  But making the temporary table with all the views is not the hard part, I have that working already.  We just need to populate the cells.  Without this need, I do understand that its simply a matter of hard-coding the procedure calls.  I do NOT want to hardcode it.

Comment: Also, your point on a temp table being dropped is not entirely correct, as I could simply declare it as a Global temp table within my Dynamic Sql, then make sure I drop it later.

Comment: Global temp tables create concurrency issues in applications like this.  Be careful.   Pretty much your own choice is going to be to dynamically generate a query to populate your temp table and run it with `exec` or `sp_executesql`.  It shouldn't be hard to write, but it will be messy and very procedural.

Comment: @Donnie- Concurrency isn't a real concern here as only 1 user should ever be using this page at a time.  Can you give me a tip on how to pass the username and role into the IsUserInRole stored proc?  This is where I'm lost.

Comment: If `IsUserInRole` was a scalar udf, you could just put it directly in the `select` part of your statement with the column names as parameters.  Ie, `select IsUserInRole(UserNameCol, RoleCol) ...`

Comment: Ok, but how do I get the RoleCol put into it?  I can make a scalar udf that will do what IsUserInRole does, and I can reference the username value, but how do I get the columnname into text like that?

Comment: I think I misread your qusestion.  Do you want the actual `RoleName` values to be columns?

Comment: No, but I have to pass the actual RoleName into the UDF to get the true or false (which shows if the user is in the role).  How do I reference the column name from within some kind of loop or cursor?

Comment: Ok, now I have a new wrinkle (but since I never stated this before I'll award the bounty regardless of an answer to this).  Can you see a way this can be done in sql server 2000 which doesn't support pivots?

Comment: Surprisingly, the most important part of your help was that I needed to convert the stored proc into a user defined function.  Now it works great, and it dynamically adds roles when I add them.  I did not use the cross join or pivot.  Thanks.